# Git Merge Request

Tags: r, git, github, merge

Here is my concern about 'Merge Request' on Git using RStudio.

So, I have pushed a File called 'A' on my git repository which however I don't want to merge it to the main repository.

I have a file called 'B' which I am planning to push and do the merge request with it.

Q: When I do the merge request for merging the 'B' file, is the 'A' file will be merged at the same time too? If so, is there any way that I can manually choose which file I want to merge among the files that are already pushed to my own repository? or Should I pull the 'A' File before the merge request?

I will appreciate for answers!!

Comment: Create a branch with files you want to merge.

Comment: You seem confused about how Git works.  Git is a _project_ based version control system.  When you commit in Git, you take a snapshot of _every_ file in your project.

Comment: As Tim Biegeleisen said, Git generally (and specifically for fetch/push ops) deals in entire *commits* at a time. Each commit holds a full source tree. Merges operate on entire file-trees.